# How can I silently deploy an MSI installation at the user level using the SCCM tool?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, sccm

I have an MSI installer which supports only user level installation, how can I deploy that silently deploy to all the users using SCCM tool without user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common workaround could be:

- Create a Package that copies the User-Level Installer somehow to each Computer by SCCM. i.Ex. copy that MSI to C:\ProgramData\SomeFolder\your_installer.msi
- Also create an Active Setup Entry (using the same SCCM distribution Package) in the Registry with the correctly configured `StubPath` that has a value like:

  `msiexec.exe /i C:\ProgramData\SomeFolder\your_installer.msi /qn`

This will then install that MSI for each user logging on to that Computer.

Unfortunatly handling Uninstallations might be more complicated (User Context). Removing the SCCM Package will just stop further installations for new Users.